# Is there a JSCS Eclipse Plugin?

Tags: javascript, eclipse, eclipse-plugin, jscs

Is there an eclipse plugin for JSCS or equivalent? If not, what is the best way to enforce JS style guidelines through eclipse?

Answer (score 1):

[tern.java](https://github.com/angelozerr/tern.java) provides a tern linter for [JSCS Validation](https://github.com/angelozerr/tern.java/wiki/Tern-Linter-JSCS). This linter must be improved, so don't hesitate to [create issues](https://github.com/angelozerr/tern.java/issues) to improve it.